# How to use the constellation diagram with border but without colors

Tags: diagrams, smartdiagram

I like to draw the below diagram without colours but i need the borders

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{
  planet size=2cm, 
  distance planet-text=0.1,
  distance planet-satellite=2.5cm,
  /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<-}
} 
\smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{
  MaxWalkSAT,max\_tries,max\_flips,target,p, gew.Klaus
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\tikzset{planet/.append style={
 draw=blue,thick
 },
 satellite/.append style={
 draw=red
 },
 }

\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{
  planet size=2cm,
  planet color = none,
  distance planet-text=0.1,
  distance planet-satellite=2.5cm,
  /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<-},
   satellite fill opacity=0,
}
\smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{
  MaxWalkSAT,max\_tries,max\_flips,target,p, gew.Klaus
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can remove the fill with

```
planet color = none,
satellite fill opacity=0
```

and then append the styles like

```
\tikzset{planet/.append style={
 draw=blue,thick
 },
 satellite/.append style={
 draw=red
 },
}
```

Or add directly to `\smartdiagramset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{
  planet size=2cm,
  planet color = none,                                   %%<<-- this 
  distance planet-text=0.1,
  distance planet-satellite=2.5cm,
  /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<-},
  /tikz/planet/.append style={draw=blue,thick},          %%<<-- this 
  /tikz/satellite/.append style={draw=red},              %%<<-- this 
  satellite fill opacity=0,                              %%<<-- this 
}
\smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{
  MaxWalkSAT,max\_tries,max\_flips,target,p, gew.Klaus
}

\end{document}
```

The following can be done too:

```
\smartdiagramset{
  planet size=2cm,
  %planet color = none,
  distance planet-text=0.1,
  distance planet-satellite=2.5cm,
  /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<-},
  /tikz/planet/.append style={draw=blue,thick,fill=none},
  /tikz/satellite/.append style={draw=red,fill=none},
  %satellite fill opacity=0,
}
```

---

One can change the shape of planets and satellites too.

```
\smartdiagramset{
  planet size=2cm,
  planet color = none,                                   %%<<-- this
  distance planet-text=0.1,
  distance planet-satellite=3.5cm,
  /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<-},
  /tikz/planet/.append style={draw=blue,thick,rectangle,rounded corners=5mm},          %%<<-- this
  /tikz/satellite/.append style={draw=red,rectangle,rounded corners=5mm},              %%<<-- this
  satellite fill opacity=0,                              %%<<-- this
}
```

[image]

Comment: i like to change the circle to curved rectangle or curved square

Comment: @Prasad: OK I have added that option too.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to adjust the size of the planet with respect to the size of the text?