# How do I make these two diagrams in Beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Consider:

[image]

How do I make diagram 1 and 3 in the following picture in Beamer?

For example, I tried:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%>

\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}

\smartdiagram[constellation diagram]
    {Love,Trust,Self-control,Journey,Obedience}

\end{document}
```

It looks similar to diagram 3, but the arrow is in the opposite direction.

Comment: I think I have found a similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252531/smart-diagram-constellation-diagram-change-direction-of-the-arrows?rq=1

Answer (score 14):

All examples from the documentation of [`smartdiagram`](http://texdoc.net/show.php?pkg=smartdiagram)

---

**Diagram 1:** (with a little help from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263961/36296)

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{
  /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<-},
  /tikz/satellite/.append style={rectangle,rounded corners=5mm},
}

\smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{
  Build a program,Set up,Run,Analyze,Modify Add,Check
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Diagram 2:**

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{planet color=orange!60,
  distance planet-satellite=3cm
 }
 \smartdiagram[connected constellation diagram]
  {Build a program,Set up,Run,Analyze,Modify~/\\ Add,Check}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Diagram 3:**

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}

\smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{
 Build a program,Set up,Run,Analyze,Modify~/\\ Add
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Diagram 4:**

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}

\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{%
  Build a program,Set up,Run,Analyze,Modify Add,Check
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Ginger "He that can have patience can have what he will." -- Benjamin Franklin

Answer (score 7):

TikZ version

diagram 1

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.arrows}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.29,0.5,0.74}
\definecolor{myred}{rgb}{0.73,0.32,0.3}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0.59,0.73,0.34}
\definecolor{myviolet}{rgb}{0.49,0.39,0.62}
\definecolor{myturquoise}{rgb}{0.28,0.67,0.76}
\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{0.97,0.58,0.27}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    myarrow/.style={single arrow,single arrow head extend=.1cm,anchor=east,minimum height=1.8cm,minimum width=.8cm},
    myrectangle/.style={rectangle,rounded corners=2,draw=white,text=white,inner sep=.5cm,align=center}]
\node(a)[draw=myblue,circle,fill=myblue,text=white,inner sep=.2cm,outer sep=.2cm]{Discipline};
\node(b)[draw=myred,fill=myred,myarrow]at(a.west){};
\node(c)[draw=mygreen,fill=mygreen,myarrow,rotate=-45]at(a.north west){};
\node(d)[draw=myviolet,fill=myviolet,myarrow,rotate=-90]at(a.north){};
\node(e)[draw=myturquoise,fill=myturquoise,myarrow,rotate=-135]at(a.north east){};
\node(f)[draw=myorange,fill=myorange,myarrow,rotate=-180]at(a.east){};
\node(g)[myrectangle,fill=myred,anchor=east]at(b.mid){Self\\Control};
\node(g)[myrectangle,fill=mygreen,anchor=south east]at(c.mid){Trust};
\node(g)[myrectangle,fill=myviolet,anchor=south]at(d.mid){Obedience};
\node(g)[myrectangle,fill=myturquoise,anchor=south west]at(e.mid){Journey};
\node(g)[myrectangle,fill=myorange,anchor=west]at(f.mid){Love};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

diagram 3

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.arrows}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.29,0.5,0.74}
\definecolor{myred}{rgb}{0.73,0.32,0.3}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0.59,0.73,0.34}
\definecolor{myviolet}{rgb}{0.49,0.39,0.62}
\definecolor{myturquoise}{rgb}{0.28,0.67,0.76}
\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{0.97,0.58,0.27}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[myarrow/.style={single arrow,single arrow head extend=.1cm,anchor=west,minimum height=.8cm,minimum width=.8cm},
    mycircle/.style={circle,text=white,inner sep=.2cm,outer sep=.2cm,minimum width=2.5cm}]
\node(a)[draw=myblue,mycircle,fill=myblue,circle,text=white,inner sep=.2cm,outer sep=.2cm]{Discipline};
\node(b)[draw=myturquoise,fill=myturquoise,myarrow,rotate=220]at(a.220){};
\node(c)[draw=myviolet,fill=myviolet,myarrow,rotate=320]at(a.320){};
\node(d)[draw=mygreen,fill=mygreen,myarrow,rotate=30]at(a.30){};
\node(e)[draw=myorange,fill=myorange,myarrow,rotate=150]at(a.150){};
\node(f)[draw=myred,fill=myred,myarrow,rotate=90]at(a.90){};
\node(g)[draw=myred,fill=myred,mycircle,anchor=south]at(f.east){Self Control};
\node(g)[draw=myorange,fill=myorange,mycircle,anchor=-40]at(e.east){Love};
\node(g)[draw=myviolet,fill=myviolet,mycircle,anchor=140]at(c.east){Obedience};
\node(g)[draw=mygreen,fill=mygreen,mycircle,anchor=-140]at(d.east){Trust};
\node(g)[draw=myturquoise,fill=myturquoise,mycircle,anchor=40]at(b.east){Journey};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

this is just a starting point, the code could very likely optimized, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [`smartdiagram`](https://ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram)-Package. Or use the Tkiz itself.

Comment: Yes I wanted to use smartdiagram, but I still do not know how.

Comment: @Ginger Then provide a minimal working example. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: for example, I tried : \smartdiagram[constellation diagram]
    {Love,Trust,Self-control,Journey,Obedience}
It looks similar as diagram 3 but the arrow is in opposite direction.

Comment: @Ginger Don't comment. Put your code in your question. You can _edit_ it. And use markdown to format your code.

Comment: Provide a *Minimal Working Example* and not just a line of code!

Comment: @Ginger If you want to change the direction of the arrows in diagram 1 to make it like figure 3 in your example simply change "append style={<-}" in " append style={->}" in the code provided by buhtz.